# Tikz and figures in 3-space

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, gnuplot

[image]

How can I draw this in LaTeX? I can do with a lot of segments but I think  that there is other easy way to do it. And how  can I add this gray blackground to images that give that spatial view.

Comment: sorry, mobil version of TSE don't have the icon for upload photos

Comment: They are just rectangles. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm bad in tikz, i draw in Geogebra and then export it to tikz code, I am doing 4 segments for each rectangle, and in stile i put - - - - and ____ for diferent kind of lines

Comment: this is the way? and for each $P_i$ I have to do

    \draw (coordinates) {anchor=north west latex}{$P$};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot in 3-D coordinates. This should get you started:

[image]

Note that the order that you draw the different parts of the diagram is important: I have drawn the shaded section first so that it is "behind" the other lines.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
    \draw[dashed,fill=blue!20](1,0,-1) -- (-1,0,-1) -- (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw(-1,-1,0)node[anchor=south west]{$P_1$} -- (1,-1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (-1,1,0) -- cycle;
    \draw(1,0,1)node[anchor=south east]{$P_2$} -- (-1,0,1) -- (-1,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, it helps me a lot, thanks. One question, why do you use mwe? what is that?

Comment: sorry again jeje, the gray blackground? how can I do that? this blackground makes a spatial view with a decrecent tone.

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez The [mwe package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) provides a special class file that includes some useful things for writing [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/). It is sometimes useful for answering questions on TeX.SX but you shouldn't use it in real life. It is isn't needed here.

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez I have added some shading to the diagram. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now i can do the rest alone, thanks!